# Change ARGB color int's single channel value

Tags: int, bit-manipulation, argb

If I have a color:

```
int color = 0x1a2cf3bb; // just an example
```

How can I change, for examle, just the R channel with the value:

```
int red = 0xfe; // another example
```

So that color becomes:

```
color = 0x1afef3bb;
```

Comment: color = (color & 0xFF00FFFF) | 0x00FE0000.

Comment: Which programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int result = (color & 0xff00ffff) | red;
```